# elasticsearch : create a dictionary

Tags: elasticsearch, document, n-gram

I do have a file which contains a lot of words (a word per line) for exemple:

```
Apple "\n" Home "\n" Banana ...
```

and I want to use it in elastic search in order if I write a correct word, it would return the line in my file which contains thats word (ex in query if I write banana it will return line 3, and the word : banana)

or if its a wrong one, to return the most approximate word and it's line in my file using maybe `ngram filter`   (if I write banona it return 3 correct word : banana)

**My question is:**

How can I create that document in elasticsearch and the query?

Comment: First and fore from your question I have got some which would be helpful.
First create a sample document like this 
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/testindex1/file/1" -d'
{
  "fruit":"Apple"
}'

You need to have field and the field value while creating a document.
Now search for apple:
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/testindex1/file/_search" -d'
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "fruit": "Apple"
    }
  }
}'

Comment: Thank you for answering. But I'm wondering how could I create a dictionnary that contains a lot of words. Should I create an Array in my document  as for exp [Banana, Apple..]?

Comment: Ya it would be the better option if you consider all words in array format.

Comment: okey
and for searching, i noticed if i write q=word:"banana " it return the correct index but if I write banano, therez an error.. how could I integreate some filter to take misspelling correction such as Ngram

Comment: One option is you can use fuzzy query and can please look into this link which is attahced.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/fuzzy-query.html